# According to the The Yalkut Yosef, should one Mishloach Manot be large to serve as a meal?

Tags: halacha, purim, mishloach-manot

Chazon Ovadyah (pp 129-31) learns from Megillah 7b that one should send enough food that could serve as a meal.

What is the opinion of The Yalkut Yosef - Is it obligatory to send food large enough to serve as a meal?

Comment: Is your question, in other words, does son agree with father?

Answer (score 2):

He rules that it's preferable. [Yalkut Yosef (Purim page 721)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=56811&st=&pgnum=721)

Comment: not compulsory right?

Comment: That's my impression, correct.